# Replacing one test string with another in particular column

Tags: text-processing, awk, replace

I would like to replace "CC" with "C"  and "AA" with A" in a particular column of Tab delimited file (using `awk` probably).

Comment: My input data file abc.txt has this "20131008","0004","0568","98" I ran this command to replace the text
nawk -F, -vOFS=',' '{gsub("0568","0808",$3); print }' abc.txt In the output the delimiter "," is replaced with a space. The output looks like this "20131008" "0004" "0568" "98". Can someone please help with this? I tried to replace the -vOFS but doesnt work.

Answer (score 10):

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '{ gsub("CC", "C", $1) ; gsub("AA", "A", $1) ; print }'
```

Replace `$1` with the column that you wish to modify.

Comment: In case the delimiter has to be kept, a `-vOFS='\t'` option may be added.

Comment: @manatwork Good point, added.

Comment: fantastic! works as per usual!!!

Comment: Some versions of `awk` don't have a `gsub` function. How would you do it then? Can `sed` be used instead?

Comment: @rahmu - `gsub()` has been defined by POSIX for over 20 years, so my suggestion would be to get a version of awk that isn't downright awful ;-)

Comment: @ChrisDown - Oh yes, I completely afree with you! If only the good people at Sun-now-Oracle would agree with the both of us, then my job would be a little bit better and life would be good, wouldn't it?

Comment: @rahmu sed would be harder due to 2 issues: 1) particular column requirement. 2) Tab delimiter (you might be able to match \t, but replace programmatically has issues) . In short, if at all possible, avoid using tab as delimiter - it doesn't guarantee same number of chars between OSs or even apps in same OS (you can change vim's handling of tab according to file type for example) and some apps would even silently transform the tab to spaces. CSV is a universal format for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have access to `gsub()`, but you do have access to `split()`, you could just create the equivalent thusly:

Given the input

```
AA      AA      CC      CC      AA      CC
```

the following `awk` script

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t";
    split("1 3 5", Fields);
    split("A C", Replacements);
}
{
    for (i in Fields) {
        for (j in Replacements) {
            Replace = Replacements[j];
            sub(Replace Replace, Replace, $Fields[i]);
        }
    }
    print;
}
```

would produce the desired results for fields 1, 3, and 5:

```
A       AA      C       CC      A       CC
```

Even without `split()` it's possible if you want to hard-code the `Fields` and `Replacements` arrays in the `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 0):

To find and replace in one field use this command:

```
sed 's/whatyouwanttofind/whatyouwanttoreplace/field#'
```

i.e. you echo this:

```
$echo -e "1are,2are,3are,4are\n5are,6are,7are,8are"

1are,2are,3are,4are

5are,6are,7are,8are
```

and you want to do this

```
$echo -e "1are,2are,3are,4are\n5are,6are,7are,8are" |  sed 's/are/arrr/2'

1are,2**arrr**,3are,4are

5are,6**arrr**,7are,8are
```