# How can I use gsub with a pattern? And how to tell it which file to awk?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I've read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40767) that I can replace the values of all columns containing a particular text using

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '{ gsub("CC", "C", $1) ; gsub("AA", "A", $1) ; print }'
```

But where do I tell `awk` the name of the file I want to perform this operation on? And instead of searching for the literal "CC", how can search for a column matching the pattern `A{7}`?

Comment: Filename would be the last argument!

Comment: `awk` is like most Unix commands: it reads from files named on the command line, or from `stdin` if no filenames are given.

Answer (score 0):

Test file:

```
A       CC      _AAAAAAA_       foo
C       AA      _AAAAAAA_       foo

awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '{ gsub("CC", "C", $1) ; gsub("AA", "A", $1) ; print; '\
'for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /A{7}/) print "   $" i ": " $i;}' file
A       CC      _AAAAAAA_       foo
   $3: _AAAAAAA_
C       AA      _AAAAAAA_       foo
   $3: _AAAAAAA_
```